# Not able to set up zookeeper in replicated mode

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to set up zookeeper in replicated node with 3 server.

my config file is like this

```
tickTime=2000 
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/ 
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

I am getting following exception

```
QuorumPeer:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:FastLeaderElection@642] - Adding vote 

2009-09-23 15:30:28,099 - WARN  [WorkerSender Thread:QuorumCnxManager@336] - 
Cannot open channel to 3 at election address zoo1/172.21.31.159:3888 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)> at 
sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:507) 
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:146) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:
```

All ports are open and ssh, telnet are also working.

Thanks

Comment: Have you started zookeepers on all three machines? Is the same error on all three?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick checklist:

- Do you have a `/var/lib/zookeeper/myid` file?
- Are ids defined in that file in sync with machine names/IPs defined in config (zoo1 having id 1, etc...)?

Comment: HI Slartibartfast : I face the similar issue. But I've placed the myid files under the zookeeper-data directory. And these numbers are in synch with the given inside zoo.cfg file. I've posted a separate question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732514/zookeeper-ensemble-not-coming-up

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but I had to use `0.0.0.0` as a host name in Zookeeper config for a each of the servers.

I.e:

**Server 1**:

*myid*

```
1
```

*zoo.cfg*

```
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=X.X.X.2:2888:3888
server.3=X.X.X.3:2888:3888
```

**Server 2**:

*myid*

```
2
```

*zoo.cfg*

```
server.1=X.X.X.1:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=X.X.X.3:2888:3888
```

**Server 3**:

*myid*

```
3
```

*zoo.cfg*

```
server.1=X.X.X.1:2888:3888
server.2=X.X.X.2:2888:3888
server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
```