# Zookeeper ensemble not coming up

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to configure the ensemble of 3 nodes following the [documentation](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup). All of them are on Linux Ubuntu.
 on all the three nodes configuration file looks like this :

**zoo.cfg under $ZOOKEEPER_HOME/conf**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/zkuser/zookeeper_data
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=ip.of.zk1:2888:3888
server.2=ip.of.zk2:2888:3888
server.3=ip.of.zk3:2888:3888
```

I've also placed respective "`myid`" files under `/home/zkuser/zookeeper_data/` directory.
This myid files contain 1 which is on node (ip.of.zk1), so on and so forth.

When I start the zk server using bin/zkServer.sh start without showing any exception on the console.
However when I open the zookeeper.out files under bin directory I see the following errors.

```
2014-11-04 00:23:49,120 [myid:3] - WARN  [WorkerSender[myid=3]:QuorumCnxManager@382] - Cannot open channel to 1 at election address /ip.of.zk1:3888
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:385)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:341)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:449)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
2014-11-04 00:23:49,123 [myid:3] - WARN  [WorkerSender[myid=3]:QuorumCnxManager@382] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /ip.of.zk2:3888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:385)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:341)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:449)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

**Note** :I've opened the appropriate ports using iptables on each machines.
For example :
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  IP.of.ZK1       anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  IP.of.ZK2       anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  IP.of.ZK3       anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Can anyone please tell me what I've been missing ?

Regards,
JE

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that:

- you have started the Zookeeper server on all 3 servers
- all servers run in non-error mode by running `echo ruok | netcat ip.of.zk2 2181`. If ok, the server should respond with `imok` (FYI, here's a [list of all supported 4-letter commands](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands))
- `/home/zkuser/zookeeper_data/myid` contains values 1/2/3 for each server, respectively
- you can ping other 2 servers from the first server

If interested, I have created a vagrant+ansible script to create a 3-node virtual Zookeeper cluster, see https://github.com/mkrcah/virtual-zookeeper-cluster

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. I have got some hints of what the problem may be from [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/zookeeper-user/201506.mbox/%3CetPan.55878aa5.6b8b4567.1d0@Rahuls-MacBook-Pro.local%3E) and [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/zookeeper-user/201402.mbox/%3CCACUUc6AxhdJ8-H_RE-7FA-HsQM3hFaJCT8XLqnBO68xJMjPzOQ@mail.gmail.com%3E). In my case, the output of the command `netstat -plutn`
was showing something including `127.0.0.1:3888` for the election port 3888. I have solved the problem by changing part of zoo.cfg on server n, from something like

```
server.1=name.of.s1:2888.3888
...
server.n=localhost:2888:3888
...
```

to

```
server.1=name.of.s1:2888.3888
...
server.n=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
...
```

After a ZooKeeper restart, the output of `netstat -plutn` includes `:::3888`.

Apparently this is needed for ZooKeeper to properly expose the election port, in this case 3888.